# Django inlineformset_factory with predefined modelchoice field rendered as text

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django app that manages processing jobs and I'm trying to create a user-friendly process request form. Basically, there's a Process model that defines a process and has a related ProcessInput model to define the input parameters. Mirroring these 2 models to create "instances" of a Process are the ProcessRequest and ProcessRequestInputValue models.

The requirement here is that for a new ProcessRequest there must be a complete set of ProcessRequestInputValues matching all the ProcessInputs. Currently, I'm using an inlineformset_factory to create a form for submitting process requests which allows entering all the input values at the same time. I've also provided the initial data to pre-populate the input choices. This is working, but the user can change the input value category because it is a ModelChoiceField. I'd like to "fix" this value and display it as text, essentially a read-only text widget.

Here's the relevant code. First, the models:

```
class Process(models.Model):
    process_name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class ProcessInput(models.Model):
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process)
    input_name = models.CharField()
    default_value = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('process', 'input_name'),)

class ProcessRequest(models.Model):
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process)
    request_user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)

class ProcessRequestInputValue(models.Model):
    process_request = models.ForeignKey(ProcessRequest)
    process_input = models.ForeignKey(ProcessInput)
    value = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('process_request', 'process_input'),)
```

The forms are simply:

```
class ProcessRequestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessRequest
        exclude = ('process', 'request_user')

class ProcessRequestInputValueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessRequestInputValue
        exclude = ('process_request',)
```

And finally the code in the view for the formset:

```
PRInputValueFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ProcessRequest,
    ProcessRequestInputValue,
    form=ProcessRequestInputValueForm,
    extra=process.processinput_set.count(),
    can_delete=False,
)

form = ProcessRequestForm(instance=process_request)

initial_data = list()

for process_input in process.processinput_set.all():
    initial_data.append({'process_input': process_input})

formset = PRInputValueFormSet(
    instance=process_request,
    initial=initial_data)
```

This works, and it keeps all the filled out information on form errors. However, like I stated above the form shows the process inputs as a drop-down because it is a ModelChoiceField.

For example, say we have a Process called "Add Numbers" and has 2 inputs "NumberA" and "NumberB". Here's a screen grab from the ProcessRequest form with the formset:

[image]

I'd like to essentially display the choice as the value's label. I've tried a couple approaches but haven't found anything that works well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like a hack, but the only solution I've found so far is to create a dummy form field to store a label value. Below is the code I have so far.

I'm not super happy with this and I'd love to see any other solutions.

**forms.py:**

```
class ProcessRequestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessRequest
        exclude = ('process', 'request_user')


class ProcessRequestInputValueForm(ModelForm):
    value_label = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    process_input = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProcessInput.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = ProcessRequestInputValue
        exclude = ('process_request',)
```

**views.py:**

```
def create_process_request(request, process_id):
    process = get_object_or_404(Process, pk=process_id)
    process_request = ProcessRequest(process=process, request_user=request.user)

    PRInputValueFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        ProcessRequest,
        ProcessRequestInputValue,
        form=ProcessRequestInputValueForm,
        extra=process.processinput_set.count(),
        can_delete=False,
    )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # validate the form / formset and save
    else:
        form = ProcessRequestForm(instance=process_request)
        initial_data = list()

        for process_input in process.processinput_set.all():
            # note 'value_label' is used for the 'value' field's label
            initial_data.append(
                {
                    'process_input': process_input,
                    'value_label': process_input.input_name
                })

        formset = PRInputValueFormSet(instance=process_request, initial=initial_data)

    return render_to_response(
        'create_process_request.html',
        {
            'process': process,
            'form': form,
            'formset': formset,
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

**template:**

```
Process: {{ process.process_name }}<br/>

<form action="{% url 'create_process_request' process.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  <Inputs: <br/>

    {% for input_form in formset %}
      {% for hidden_field in input_form.hidden_fields %}

        {% if hidden_field.name == 'process_input' %}
          {{ hidden_field.as_hidden }}
        {% elif hidden_field.name == 'value_label' %}

          {# Needed if form submission has errors, else our custom label goes away #}
          {# Could be used to "hack" our custom label on POST %}
          {{ hidden_field.as_hidden }}

          {# Our custom dynamic label #}
          {{ hidden_field.value }}

        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {{ input_form.value }}

      {% if input_form.value.errors %}
        {{ input_form.value.errors|striptags }}
      {% endif %}

      <hr/>

    {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And a much more usable form:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it for my inline_formsets was to simply exclude the field you don't wish to display in the form, here the process_input as well as the process_request

```
class ProcessRequestInputValueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessRequestInputValue
        exclude = ('process_request','process_input')
```

Now set a property value on the underlying model (ProcessRequestInputValue) to answer what you do want, in your case the Process object on the ProcessInput I'm guessing:

```
@property
def my_process(self):
    return self.process_input.process
```

then in your template, just call that unary method directly, from inside the form loop:

```
<span>Process Input: {{form.instance.my_process}}</span>
```

which will call the unicode method on the Process object

This avoids having to make any complicated ReadOnlyWidgets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried disabling?

```
some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=my_choices, 
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not display the widget as a combobox